# How to use CIFilter CiColorCube

Tags: ios, core-image, cifilter

can someone explain me, how does this filter works, i saw WWDC 2012 and documentation and still don’t understand quite. Where and how to define cube color map. Is it in .h or .m file? I have ViewController.h and .m, where i working with some filters and i need to use CiColorCube filter but i just don't know how. This is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // here i would like to use CIColorCube
    CIImage *inputImage = [[CIImage alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.jpg"]];
    CIImage *inputBackgroundImg = [[CIImage alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpeg"]];
    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    vignette = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIVignette"];
    [vignette setValue:inputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
    [vignette setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.5] forKey:@"inputRadius"];
    [vignette setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.9] forKey:@"inputIntensity"];
    sourceOC = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISourceOverCompositing"];
    [sourceOC setValue:vignette.outputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
    [sourceOC setValue:inputBackgroundImg forKey:@"inputBackgroundImage"];
    maskToAlpha = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIMaskToAlpha"];
    [maskToAlpha setValue:inputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
    CIImage *outputImage = maskToAlpha.outputImage;
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:outputImage.extent]];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: As I understand, it replaces colours from colours array. For ex., you can make image mostly black and white and left red colour. This colour array should be converted to NSData. Unfortunately, I didn't found good tutorials on this theme, but I think that you can create those arrays in Photoshop or 3D Lut Creator apps.

Answer (score 1):

In Apple's Developer Library, there is a document on ['Subclassing CIFilter: Recipes for Custom Effects'](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_filer_recipes/ci_filter_recipes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH4-SW1) that shows how to make the color map..

Also, in XCode you can look up the ImageApp sample code, and it also shows how in ImageFilter.m.